# Passing fullstops (periods) and forward slashes in a GET request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, encoding

I have built a form that submits values to Wufoo as a GET request in the URL. I cannot get it to work if any of the values (in a textarea) contain a line-break or a forward slash. Is there a way to encode these in a URL?

This is being done in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 2):

I thought Rails would do that for you.  But if you need to do it manually, you can use CGI::escape, e.g.

```
 > require 'cgi'
 ...
 > CGI.escape("hello%there\nworld")
 => "hello%25there%0Aworld"
```

EDIT: 
Actually, CGI does not seem to escape a dot.  URI can be used instead, it takes an extra parameter that lets you list extra characters you want escaped:

```
URI.escape("hello.there%world", ".")
```